# PHP sign in form errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn PHP by creating a small login form. I have 2 errors. First, when I sign in, I'll only be able to sign in to one user which is the user that I have in a database with the ID of 1. I have 3 users in total and I can't sign in to the other users. Second, I'd like to make it so when I'm signed in, I can't access the login form.

I am connected to the database.

Login form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$securePassword = md5($password);

{   // Select table(s)
        $tUsers_Select = "SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users";
        $tUsers_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tUsers_Select);
}
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tUsers_Select_Query);

    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];

    if ($username == $dbusername AND $securePassword == $dbpassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        header("Location: home.php");
    }   else {
        echo "Incorrect name or password";
    }

?>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="welcome-msg">
            <h1 class="huge">Welcome!</h1>
            <h3 class="medium">Please sign in</h3>

            <form id="login-form" action="/lr/index.php" method="post">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

                <button type="submit" name="submit">Log in</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php

session_start();


{   // Select table(s)
    $tUsers_Select = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $tUsers_Select_Query = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $tUsers_Select);
}

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {


    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];

    // echo $username."<br />";
    // echo $password."<br />";
    // echo $securePassword."<br />";

}   else {
    header(
        "Location: /lr/index.php"
    );
}

?>

    <div id="main-content">
        <h1 class="huge">Welcome back, <?php echo $username ?>!</h1>
        <a href="/lr/logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>


</body>
```

Logout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

    session_start();
    session_destroy();

?>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="welcome-msg">
            <h1 class="huge">Bye-Bye!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

If you need any more details, please comment.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect))` to `mysqli_query()`. You may be surprised at what pops out.

Comment: *"I am connected to the database."* - Using `mysqli_` am sure ;-) surprising how many we see using `mysql_` or PDO to initially connect with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, I'm using mysqli_

Comment: Didn't get any errors after adding the code @Fred-ii-

Comment: A suggestion, instead of just md5 for your hashing I would use PBKDF2.  Here's a link to an example: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm  Also in your example, I would do something like the following: $securePassword = md5($password); Then SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users where username = ? and password = ?, then substitute your username and password from your derived values.

Comment: @Severun I am aware that md5 is insecure. Thanks though

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: If you're aware that MD5 is insecure, why are you using it? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Severun You fixed one of my problems. Now I can sign in with any users. Thanks!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I haven't learned yet about Mysql Security.

Comment: You have some extra curly braces in your code at the beginning - I am surprised that doesn't throw errors.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard for the link. I'll make sure to check it out.

Comment: Make sure you run username through mysql_safe_string, or bind the parameters so you don't get SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's just to wrap the code in Sublime.

http://i.imgur.com/E41fJ4I.png

Comment: Oh, here's a built in PBKDF2 hasher http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php

Comment: Uh....what? Wrap the code in Sublime? Sublime is just a text editor and has *nothing* to do with naked sets of curly braces in the wild.

Comment: @Severun you really should use the proper methods to [hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard, true if you're using strictly PHP, I find using pdkdf2 works better when maintaining password hashes across multiple languages.

Comment: @JayBlanchard http://gyazo.com/afe2e99c04b95c886c4b0d968b9550d9

Comment: ^ What is that supposed to be?

Comment: It's how I'm using the curly braces to hide the code inside them. I've been using then and I haven't had a problem.

Comment: in order to sign in as a particular member, SELECT requires a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're getting all users and after fetching first from that, you check your inputs with that. It's wrong and will always check your input with the first record of table.  In addition using `crypt()` to hash password is better.
Instead of that, change your query to fetch the user with the info you have:

```
$securePassword = crypt($password, $password);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param( "ss", $username, $securePassword);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->num_rows === 1)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    //$_SESSION['password'] = $password; You don't need that
}
else
    echo "Incorrect name or password";
```

And finally if you want to hide the login form from logged in users just wrap your login form between the following `if` block:

```
<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
    <script>window.location = 'home.php';</script>
<?PHP else: ?>
    <!-- Form element -->
<?PHP endif; ?>
```

Comment: Instead of hiding the login form, I want to redirect them to the home page.

I used this code but it doesn't work:

`if (isset($_SESSION['username']) AND isset($_SESSSION['password'])) {
   header("home.php");
  }`

Comment: `header()` won't work after you send any output buffer. instead of that use javascript to redirect user: `<script>window.location = 'home.php';</script>`

Comment: doesn't work means it didn't redirect? any error in your inspector console tab? just `echo` something instead of that. Is that visible? Also see my updated code

Comment: I used `if (isset($_SESSION['username']) AND isset($_SESSSION['password'])) {
   echo "Yes";
  }` and "Yes" did not show up. When I'm logged in, I can go to the home page, and the login, and I can go back to the homepage and I'll still be logged in. When I log out, the session gets destroyed. I'm not sure if I could use an if statement to check if the session has not been destroyed. If it has, then redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: just before `if($stmt->num_rows....` use this code and tell me the result `print_r($stmt);die();`. Be sure your `error_reporting` is enable

Comment: @FocuZst just send another parameter to `crypt` as I edited in code, let me know what will happen

Comment: And of course you know that you must change your password which stored in db to passwords which hashed by `crypt` not `md5` anymore

Comment: One of the errors disappeared but I still have one more:

**Warning**: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

This is the code I have: http://i.imgur.com/NFciyVh.png

Comment: Can I know that? Is that the previous one?

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I really appreciate it. I have to avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: You're welcome but it must not produce warning, is your code exactly like mine?

Comment: Well, I edited this line: `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConnect, "SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$securePassword'");` I connected it to the database.

Comment: Yes but be careful, because you didn't escape your inputs and would cause security issues. Other part of the script executed successfully or error again?

Comment: If I can help, tell me and if you're giving your desired output we're done ;)